# Jenkins Pipeline - Error "Stage skipped due to earlier failure(s)"

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, groovy, google-cloud-platform, jenkins-pipeline

I'm building a CD pipeline using Jenkins on the Google Kubernetes Engine and I'm running into problems on the first build. As shown in the output below, the pipelined stages are being skipped "due to earlier failure(s)" which I am unable to identity.

I'm very new to Jenkins so would appreciate any help.
I've also pasted the Jenkinsfile below.

OUTPUT

```
Started by user unknown or anonymous
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to https://source.developers.google.com/p/org-footprint/r/gceme
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url https://source.developers.google.com/p/org-footprint/r/gceme # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.11.0'
 > /usr/bin/git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials org-footprint
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress -- origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Seen branch in repository origin/canary
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 2 remote branches
Obtained Jenkinsfile from 45c2a3ac2fd7ec86e94d502c2f44aef083cbd7f1
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/sample-app_canary
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential source:org-footprint
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url https://source.developers.google.com/p/org-footprint/r/gceme # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from https://source.developers.google.com/p/org-footprint/r/gceme
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.11.0'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials org-footprint
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --no-tags --progress -- https://source.developers.google.com/p/org-footprint/r/gceme +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 45c2a3ac2fd7ec86e94d502c2f44aef083cbd7f1 (canary)
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f 45c2a3ac2fd7ec86e94d502c2f44aef083cbd7f1 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Version 6"
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build and push image with Container Builder)
Stage "Build and push image with Container Builder" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy Canary)
Stage "Deploy Canary" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy Production)
Stage "Deploy Production" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy Dev)
Stage "Deploy Dev" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Node is not a Kubernetes node: 
Finished: FAILURE
```

JENKINSFILE

```
pipeline {

  environment {
    PROJECT = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PROJECT_ID"
    APP_NAME = "gceme"
    FE_SVC_NAME = "${APP_NAME}-frontend"
    CLUSTER = "jenkins-cd"
    CLUSTER_ZONE = "us-east1-d"
    IMAGE_TAG = "gcr.io/${PROJECT}/${APP_NAME}:${env.BRANCH_NAME}.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
    JENKINS_CRED = "${PROJECT}"
  }

  agent {
    kubernetes {
      label 'sample-app'
      defaultContainer 'jnlp'
      yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
labels:
  component: ci
spec:
  # Use service account that can deploy to all namespaces
  serviceAccountName: cd-jenkins
  containers:
  - name: golang
    image: golang:1.10
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
  - name: gcloud
    image: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
  - name: kubectl
    image: gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
"""
}
  }
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        container('golang') {
          sh """
            ln -s `pwd` /go/src/sample-app
            cd /go/src/sample-app
            go test
          """
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Build and push image with Container Builder') {
      steps {
        container('gcloud') {
          sh "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 gcloud builds submit -t ${IMAGE_TAG} ."
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy Canary') {
      // Canary branch
      when { branch 'canary' }
      steps {
        container('kubectl') {
          // Change deployed image in canary to the one we just built
          sh("sed -i.bak 's#gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/gceme:1.0.0#${IMAGE_TAG}#' ./k8s/canary/*.yaml")
          step([$class: 'KubernetesEngineBuilder', namespace:'production', projectId: env.PROJECT, clusterName: env.CLUSTER, zone: env.CLUSTER_ZONE, manifestPattern: 'k8s/services', credentialsId: env.JENKINS_CRED, verifyDeployments: false])
          step([$class: 'KubernetesEngineBuilder', namespace:'production', projectId: env.PROJECT, clusterName: env.CLUSTER, zone: env.CLUSTER_ZONE, manifestPattern: 'k8s/canary', credentialsId: env.JENKINS_CRED, verifyDeployments: true])
          sh("echo http://`kubectl --namespace=production get service/${FE_SVC_NAME} -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'` > ${FE_SVC_NAME}")
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy Production') {
      // Production branch
      when { branch 'master' }
      steps{
        container('kubectl') {
        // Change deployed image in canary to the one we just built
          sh("sed -i.bak 's#gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/gceme:1.0.0#${IMAGE_TAG}#' ./k8s/production/*.yaml")
          step([$class: 'KubernetesEngineBuilder', namespace:'production', projectId: env.PROJECT, clusterName: env.CLUSTER, zone: env.CLUSTER_ZONE, manifestPattern: 'k8s/services', credentialsId: env.JENKINS_CRED, verifyDeployments: false])
          step([$class: 'KubernetesEngineBuilder', namespace:'production', projectId: env.PROJECT, clusterName: env.CLUSTER, zone: env.CLUSTER_ZONE, manifestPattern: 'k8s/production', credentialsId: env.JENKINS_CRED, verifyDeployments: true])
          sh("echo http://`kubectl --namespace=production get service/${FE_SVC_NAME} -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'` > ${FE_SVC_NAME}")
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy Dev') {
      // Developer Branches
      when {
        not { branch 'master' }
        not { branch 'canary' }
      }
      steps {
        container('kubectl') {
          // Create namespace if it doesn't exist
          sh("kubectl get ns ${env.BRANCH_NAME} || kubectl create ns ${env.BRANCH_NAME}")
          // Don't use public load balancing for development branches
          sh("sed -i.bak 's#LoadBalancer#ClusterIP#' ./k8s/services/frontend.yaml")
          sh("sed -i.bak 's#gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/gceme:1.0.0#${IMAGE_TAG}#' ./k8s/dev/*.yaml")
          step([$class: 'KubernetesEngineBuilder', namespace: "${env.BRANCH_NAME}", projectId: env.PROJECT, clusterName: env.CLUSTER, zone: env.CLUSTER_ZONE, manifestPattern: 'k8s/services', credentialsId: env.JENKINS_CRED, verifyDeployments: false])
          step([$class: 'KubernetesEngineBuilder', namespace: "${env.BRANCH_NAME}", projectId: env.PROJECT, clusterName: env.CLUSTER, zone: env.CLUSTER_ZONE, manifestPattern: 'k8s/dev', credentialsId: env.JENKINS_CRED, verifyDeployments: true])
          echo 'To access your environment run `kubectl proxy`'
          echo "Then access your service via http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/${env.BRANCH_NAME}/services/${FE_SVC_NAME}:80/"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Plainly at the bottom of the log is the message:

`ERROR: Node is not a Kubernetes node:`

The pipeline is failing to launch the kubernetes agent because the master (according to the log: "Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/sample-app_canary") is not in the kubernetes cluster that's been set up in the Manage Clouds section in Jenkins.